# Разметка страниц памяти Postgres по умолчанию

Tags: windows, postgresql

Опишу проблему, насколько я понимаю Postgres размечает страницы нулями, а потом их перезаписывает значениями, можно ли куда то вклиниться в коде, чтобы он размечал страницу не нулями, а какими-либо другими значениями по умолчанию?

Comment: Ну вот я это и спрашиваю, где эта функция находится.

Comment: Хочется просто посмотреть самостоятельно это, покопаться и убедиться. Если есть возможность укажите на функцию подготовки страницы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`PageInit`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_11_STABLE/src/backend/storage/page/bufpage.c#L41) в `src/backend/storage/page/bufpage.c`. Критично корректно поправить [`PageIsNew`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_11_STABLE/src/include/storage/bufpage.h#L225) макрос.

После изменения обязателен `initdb` нового кластера, т.к. вы меняете `ondisk` формат базы.

Других очевидных граблей в голову не приходит, но вероятно будут. Забитые нулями пустые страницы вещь старая. Я не слишком опытный контрибьютор, в списке рассылок [`pgsql-hackers`](https://www.postgresql.org/list/pgsql-hackers/) могут ответить опытные разработчики этой базы подробнее, но на английском.